# How to align numbers to en-dash in a table?

Tags: tables

`dcolumn` and `siunitx` packages can be used for aligning numbers to decimal point in a table.
How can I align the range values (separated using en-dash `--`) to en-dash '--', in a table?
so they appear like this:

```
A        1--2 
B       10--50 
C      500--1000 
D    0.001--0.5
```

I use the following code for generating a table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[!hb]{@{}lc@{}}
\toprule
AA & BB \\
\midrule 
A & 1--2 \\
B & 10--50 \\
C & 500--1000 \\
D & 0.001--0.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: By the way, `[!hb]` is at most an optional argument to the `table` (or any other float) environment. The optional argument to `tabular` is its vertical alignment, one of: `t` or `b`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel or `c`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution with and one without `siunitx`:

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,calc}
\newcommand*{\alignUnderEnDash}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\llap{\makebox[\widthof{--}][c]{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{--}l@{}}
    \toprule
    AA &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{BB}     \\ \midrule
    A  &                      1 & 2    \\
    B  &                     10 & 50   \\
    C  &                    500 & 1000 \\
    D  &                  0.001 & 0.5  \\
    E  & \alignUnderEnDash{10} &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}   l
                      S[table-format=3.3]
                @{--} S[table-format=4.1]
                @{}}
    \toprule
    AA &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{BB}    \\ \midrule
    A  & 1                     & 2    \\
    B  & 10                    & 50   \\
    C  & 500                   & 1000 \\
    D  & 0.001                 & 0.5  \\
    E  & \alignUnderEnDash{10} &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How would it be possible to align (center ) a single number to the en-dash in the column? like adding this row to the table and `10` is centered with en-dash: `E & 10`

Comment: @M.Reza A little bit late but see my update. :)

Answer (score 10):

The following example is perhaps not the most elegant variant. But it centers the column title `BB` on the en dash. It uses separate columns for the numbers and the dash:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}[!hb]{lr@{}>{--}c@{}l}
    \toprule
    AA & & \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\makebox[0pt]{BB}} &\\
    \midrule
    A & 1&&2 \\
    B & 10&&50 \\
    C & 500&&1000 \\
    D & 0.001&&0.5 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Because the width of column title "BB" is ignored by `\makebox(0pt){...}`, TeX will not warn, if the entry is too large.
- I have added the column separation space at the left and right of the table, because it looks better with horizontal lines IMHO.

### Support for longer column titles

The following example addresses the problem of the previous solution that the width of the column header is not taken into the account for the column widths. The example measures the width of the column header and reserves space in the first and third column of the three columns for the number range.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newdimen\tempwidthBB

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}[!hb]{lr@{}>{--}c@{}l}
    \toprule
    AA &
      \sbox0{B tattarrattat B}%
      \sbox2{--}%
      \global\tempwidthBB=\wd0 %
      \global\advance\tempwidthBB by -\wd2 %
      \rlap{\copy0 }%
      \kern.5\tempwidthBB
    & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{%
        \hphantom{--}\kern.5\tempwidthBB
      }\\
    \midrule
    A & 1&&2 \\
    B & 10&&50 \\
    C & 500&&1000 \\
    D & 0.001&&0.5 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with longer column header]

Comment: That's nice - I think the centring improves it quite a bit.

Comment: Nice solution! When 'BB' cell has lengthy text, it does not set the  proper width for the table. It seems that the values which are not in \makebox{...} actually control the width of the column. How to have latex use the length of the text in (e.g. 'BB') to set the column length?

Answer (score 7):

A slight abuse of `dcolumn` perhaps, but here you go:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\usepackage{preview}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{-}{\mbox{--}}{#1}}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ld{-1}}
        \toprule
        AA & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BB} \\
        \midrule 
        A & 1-2 \\
        B & 10-50 \\
        C & 500-1000 \\
        D & 0.001-0.5 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

We make use of the fact that dcolumn allows the input separator to be different to the output separator, avoiding the need to pick up an endash in math mode (dcolumn works in math mode).

[image: Example output]

**Edit based on Heiko Oberdiek's input - thanks**

Comment: `BB` is set in math mode at the left of the dash: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{BB}`.

Comment: `\mathrm{\--}` is a kind of soft hyphen followed by a minus sign. `\mbox{--}` or `\textendash` could be used instead.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, good spot, thanks.  Fixed with multicolumn, though my personal pref would be to centre the heading over the endash (which isn't in the question, and making ssome assumptions about relative line lengths.

Comment: Nevertheless I like the idea with `dcolumn`. If you make a full TeX file and add a image of the result I would want to upvote it.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I've gone with the `\mbox` - \textendash isn't giving me an en dash.  I'm not sure why \mathrm{--} doesn't work - but it doesn't.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I think you deserve the vote as much as me, but I will do, I think it might be good for reference.

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes I see, `\mbox{\textendash}` would do, but `\mbox{--}` is shorter.

Comment: Previous comment deleted (+1:-)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle - not too much like abusing your package then?

Comment: I've seen (and done) worse:-) (Actually it was always the intention that dcolumn could align on any character hence the clunky multiple argument form for `D` rather than hard-coding `.` (or even `.` and `,`)

Comment: This is quite easy to implement. In `d` type column, how can I center align the content if it is only a number not a range (no `--`). For example, if I want to add a fifth line to the current table but having only a number (not a range) in the second column?

Comment: @M.Reza you could use multicolumn like I used in the header row `E & \multicolumn{1}{c}{999}` for example

Comment: Using  `\begin{tabular}{ld{4.4}}` gives a better alignment (the dashes are aligned with the column header). Also, you have `\begin{tabular}[!hb]{ld{4.4}}`, why the `[!hb]` there? `[!hb]` is a placement specifier for a float. Perhaps you meant `[t]` (for top alignment?).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina good point, that was pasted from the MWE in the question, I guess the OP meant to put `\begin{table}[!hb]...\begin{tabular}`.  I'll strip it out as it's not needed.

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks. Indeed, I tried it first. but doesn't it align the number to the center of the column itself (and not the en-dash)? Is there any ways to align the number just at the center of the previous row's en-dash?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes indeed! it's not correct as Qrrbrbirlbel also pointed it out.

Comment: @M.Reza, yes, perhaps combining Gonzalo Medina's comment (use `d{4.4}` for the column specifier) and Heiko Oberdiek's answer below `\makebox(0pt){...}` would do it?  Tested and it works.