# Alignment at specific character with S column from siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

To avoid starting a new question yet again, I'll use this tread as the problem is the same as the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*\Alignment[1]{% Alignment at `--'.
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\llap{\makebox[\widthof{--}][c]{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{Something.}
 \label{tbl:4}
  \begin{tabular}{
             S[table-format=2.0]
    @{--}    S[table-format=2.0]
    @{\quad}
             S[table-format=5.0]
    @{\quad}
             S[table-format=5.0]
  }
   \toprule
    \mc{St{\o}jniveau}       & {1994} & {2005-planen} \\
    \mc{\si{\decibel}}       & {---}  & {---}         \\
   \midrule
    55                  & 59 & 19491  & 12430         \\
    60                  & 64 &  7111  &  2644         \\
    65                  & 69 &  1191  &   320         \\
    70                  & 74 &   280  &    43         \\
    \Alignment{$> 75$}  &    &    52  &     1         \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

How do I get the correct alignment in the first column?

Comment: Have you seen [How to align numbers to en-dash in a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133714)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel No. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg especially the answer there that shows how to do it if you switch back to dcolumn:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good point. `:)`

Comment: “Stojniveai” is wider than both `S` columns and the `--` dash together.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I can't disagree on that. `:)` How would you get the proper alignment?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Manually, see my answer.

Comment: Remove your self answer, then, as it became wrong. Please, also reformulate the question so that it's understandable: what *is* the other problem?

Comment: Please keep questions in place after they got answers. If you have a new question, even a similar one, post it as such and not overwrite an existing one.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Okay. I'll do that in the future. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a little manual work:

Unfortunately, the `\tablenum` macro seems to not be made for working outside of cell (or at least not only alone in there) because the digits of the first `\tablenum` showed up in the second (solves by enclosing both occurence in their own group).
Both also add horizontal space (probably because they’re usual an own column), this can be worked-around by using a box.

The `\numtablerange` syntax is made up so that one optional parameter is forwarded to both `\tablenum`s; if however two optional arguments are given then the first one goes to the first `\tablenum` and the second to the second.

I thought that one could use

```
\numtablerange[][parse-numbers=false]{75}{\hphantom{00}}
```

to simulate an open-ended range but `\tablenum` breaks then with undefined `\__siunitx_table_print_S_direct:` and `\__siunitx_table_print:`, so I went with a even more manual approach.

By the way, if the numbers are that simple you could just use `55--59` and so on in the table directly …

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\numtablerange}[1][]{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{\numtable@range{#1}}{\numtable@range{#1}[#1]}}
\def\numtable@range#1[#2]#3#4{%
  \numtablerange@boxme{\expandafter\tablenum\expandafter[\numtablerange@lopt, #1]{#3}}--%
  \numtablerange@boxme{\expandafter\tablenum\expandafter[\numtablerange@ropt, #2]{#4}}%
}
\newcolumntype{T}[3]{>{\def\numtablerange@lopt{#1}\def\numtablerange@ropt{#2}}#3}
\newcommand*{\numtablerange@boxme}[1]{{\sbox0{#1}\usebox0}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{T{table-format=2.0}{table-format=2.0}{c} @{\quad} S[table-format=5.0] @{\quad} S[table-format=5.0]}
    \toprule
    St{\o}jniveau                        & {1994} & {2005-planen} \\
    \si{\decibel}                        & {---}  & {---}         \\ \midrule
    \numtablerange{55}{59}               & 19491  & 12430         \\
    \numtablerange{60}{64}               & 7111   & 2644          \\
    \numtablerange{65}{69}               & 1191   & 320           \\
    \numtablerange{70}{74}               & 280    & 43            \\
    \makebox[\widthof{00--00}][r]{$>75$} & 52     & 1             \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is great! I would never have gotten this myself.