# Format tables with points under each other

Tags: tables

so I have this rather complicated table and I am trying to format the cells so that all points in one row are under each other.

What I tried so far was to edit the "\multicolumn{1}{l}" to include siunix code for the appropriate formatting. This works more or less alright, but not for the alpha entries, where it always places a 0 before the `.` and not for the entries for the range where there is not `.` but a `-` instead.

Does anyone have an idea for formatting the table to achieve the desired result? Maybe there is a better way than changing each multicolumn entry individually?

Thank you for any ideas!
Mil

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption[Descriptive Statistics for the Employed Scales]{Descriptive Statistics for the Employed Scales\vspace{-0.25cm}}
   \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
       \toprule
          & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath{}\textbf{$t_1$}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath{}\textbf{$t_2$}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath{}\textbf{$t_3$}\unboldmath{}} \bigstrut\\
   \cline{2-7}\cline{9-14}\cline{16-21}       &    &    &    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{range}} &    &    &    &    &    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{range}} &    &    &    &    &    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{range}} &  \bigstrut\\
   \cline{5-6}\cline{12-13}\cline{19-20}       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textit{\textbf{$M$}}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textit{\textbf{$SD$}}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textbf{$\alpha$}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{pot.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{skew}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textit{\textbf{$M$}}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textit{\textbf{$SD$}}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textbf{$\alpha$}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{pot.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{skew}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textit{\textbf{$M$}}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textit{\textbf{$SD$}}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\boldmath{}\textbf{$\alpha$}\unboldmath{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{pot.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{actual}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{skew}} \bigstrut\\
       \toprule
       Prompt engagement & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.91} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.46} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.90} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0-6} & -0.22 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  \bigstrut[t]\\
       Prompt pursuit & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.25} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.57} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.65} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0-5} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0-5} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.35} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
       Motivational reg. & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.44} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.02} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.87} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.18} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
       TV intrinsic & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.38} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.99} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.89} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.44} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.26} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.92} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.88} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.03} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.23} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.84} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.87} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.18} \\
       TV attainment & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.45} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.93} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.90} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.3-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.41} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.59} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.90} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.90} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.01} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.55} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.85} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.90} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.02} \\
       TV instrumental & \multicolumn{1}{l}{5.00} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.69} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.79} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.38} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.22} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.83} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.81} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.31} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.12} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.87} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.87} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.26} \\
       Metacognitive mon. & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.77} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.80} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.81} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.31} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.95} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.70} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.80} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-5.6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.46} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.96} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.68} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.86} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-5.7} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.75} \\
       Metacognitive reg. & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.22} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.66} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.81} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.03} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.05} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.75} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.88} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.6-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.13} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.17} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.68} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.88} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-5.9} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.61} \\
       Persistence & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.49} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.67} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.75} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.08} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.16} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.81} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.80} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.14} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.12} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.72} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.79} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.7-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.29} \\
       Elaboration & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.28} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.80} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.82} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.4-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.05} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.05} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.85} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.86} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.6-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.13} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.12} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.84} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.89} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.8-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.08} \\
       Perform. Approach & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.51} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.19} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.90} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.01} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.36} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.21} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.95} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.01} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.42} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.22} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.94} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.20} \\
       Perform. Avoidance & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.83} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.24} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.92} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.33} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.71} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.25} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.94} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.30} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.71} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.28} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.94} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.47} \\
       Mastery Approach & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.48} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.76} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.76} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.22} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.34} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.75} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.77} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.14} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.18} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.74} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.79} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.28} \\
       Mastery Avoidance & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.10} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.87} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.74} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.18} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.23} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.78} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.74} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.3-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.24} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.09} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.82} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.76} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.31} \\
       Boredom & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.02} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.88} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.73} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-5} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.72} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.92} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.02} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.87} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.32} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.92} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.94} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.85} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.43} \\
       Pleasure & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4.65} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.96} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.85} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.58} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.58} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.89} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.84} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.22} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.55} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.91} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{.82} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.48\vspace{0.2cm}} \\
       \toprule
       \multicolumn{21}{l}{\hspace{0.9cm}\vspace{-0.5cm}\footnotesize \textit{Note.} $N=330$ in $t_1$; $N=328$ in $t_2$; $N=298$ in $t_3$. $\alpha$ represents Cronbach's Alpha. Prompt pursuit is presented as a global scale.
       }
        \bigstrut[t]\\
       \end{tabular}%
       }
  \label{tab:scales}%
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: please make your code compilable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is not fitting on to a page, but you may play around with this.

Your first question is answered by `\sisetup{add-integer-zero=false}` and the second by posts like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134550) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74721) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133714).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
  \caption[Descriptive Statistics for the Employed Scales]{Descriptive Statistics for the Employed Scales}
    \sisetup{add-integer-zero=false}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    *{2}S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=0.2]
    cc
    S[table-format=-1.2]
    *{2}S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=0.2]
    cc
    S[table-format=-1.2]
    *{2}S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=0.2]
    cc
    S[table-format=-1.2]}
   \toprule
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\boldsymbol{t_1}$} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\boldsymbol{t_2}$} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{$\boldsymbol{t_3}$}\\
   \cmidrule(r){2-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-13}\cmidrule(l){14-19}      
& & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{range}} & & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{range}} & & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{range}} & \\
 \cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{11-12}\cmidrule{17-18}       
& $\boldsymbol{M}$ & $\boldsymbol{SD}$ &$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ & \textbf{pot.} & \textbf{actual} & \textbf{skew} & $\boldsymbol{M}$ & $\boldsymbol{SD}$ & $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ & \textbf{pot.} & \textbf{actual} & \textbf{skew} & $\boldsymbol{M}$ & $\boldsymbol{SD}$ & $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ & \textbf{pot.} & \textbf{actual} & \textbf{skew}  \\
       \midrule
       Prompt engagement & & & & & & & 2.91 & 1.46 & .90 & 0--6 & 0.0--6.0 & -0.22 & & & & & & \\
       Prompt pursuit & & & & & & & 3.25 & 0.57 & .65 & 0--5 & 0.0--5.0 & -0.35 & & & & & & \\
       Motivational reg. & & & & & & & 3.44 & 1.02 & .87 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.18 & & & & & & \\
       TV intrinsic & 4.38 & 0.99 & .89 & 1--6 & 1.0--6 & -0.44 & 3.26 & 0.92 & .88 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & 0.03 & 3.23 & 0.84 & .87 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.18 \\
       TV attainment & 4.45 & 0.93 & .90 & 1--6 & 1.3--6 & -0.41 & 3.59 & 0.90 & .90 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & 0.01 & 3.55 & 0.85 & .90 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & 0.02 \\
       TV instrumental & 5.00 & 0.69 & .79 & 1--6 & 3.0--6 & -0.38 & 4.22 & 0.83 & .81 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.31 & 4.12 & 0.87 & .87 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.26 \\
       Metacognitive mon. & 3.77 & 0.80 & .81 & 1--6 & 1.0--6 & -0.31 & 3.95 & 0.70 & .80 & 1--6 & 1.0--5.6 & -0.46 & 3.96 & 0.68 & .86 & 1--6 & 1.0--5.7 & -0.75 \\
       Metacognitive reg. & 4.22 & 0.66 & .81 & 1--6 & 2.1--6 & -0.03 & 4.05 & 0.75 & .88 & 1--6 & 1.6--6.0 & -0.13 & 4.17 & 0.68 & .88 & 1--6 & 1.0--5.9 & -0.61 \\
       Persistence & 4.49 & 0.67 & .75 & 1--6 & 3.0--6 & 0.08 & 4.16 & 0.81 & .80 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.14 & 4.12 & 0.72 & .79 & 1--6 & 1.7--6.0 & -0.29 \\
       Elaboration & 4.28 & 0.80 & .82 & 1--6 & 1.4--6 & -0.05 & 4.05 & 0.85 & .86 & 1--6 & 1.6--6.0 & -0.13 & 4.12 & 0.84 & .89 & 1--6 & 1.8--6.0 & -0.08 \\
       Perform. Approach & 3.51 & 1.19 & .90 & 1--6 & 1.0--6 & -0.01 & 3.36 & 1.21 & .95 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.01 & 3.42 & 1.22 & .94 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.20 \\
       Perform. Avoidance & 3.83 & 1.24 & .92 & 1--6 & 1.0--6 & -0.33 & 3.71 & 1.25 & .94 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.30 & 3.71 & 1.28 & .94 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.47 \\
       Mastery Approach & 4.48 & 0.76 & .76 & 1--6 & 2.0--6 & -0.22 & 4.34 & 0.75 & .77 & 1--6 & 2.0--6.0 & -0.14 & 4.18 & 0.74 & .79 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.28 \\
       Mastery Avoidance & 4.10 & 0.87 & .74 & 1--6 & 1.0--6 & -0.18 & 4.23 & 0.78 & .74 & 1--6 & 1.3--6.0 & -0.24 & 4.09 & 0.82 & .76 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.31 \\
       Boredom & 2.02 & 0.88 & .73 & 1--6 & 1.0--5 & 0.72 & 2.92 & 1.02 & .87 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & 0.32 & 2.92 & 0.94 & .85 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & 0.43 \\
       Pleasure & 4.65 & 0.96 & .85 & 1--6 & 1.0--6 & -0.58 & 3.58 & 0.89 & .84 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.22 & 3.55 & 0.91 & .82 & 1--6 & 1.0--6.0 & -0.48 \\
       \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
            \item \footnotesize\textit{Note.} $N=330$ in $t_1$; $N=328$ in $t_2$; $N=298$ in $t_3$. $\alpha$ represents Cronbach's Alpha. Prompt pursuit is presented as a global scale.
            \end{tablenotes}
  \label{tab:scales}%
\end{threeparttable}  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely impressive! Thank you so much! Also, this is the first time that I see how to get rid of this repetition of multicolumns and to change the unfortunate spacing in threeparttable by putting it into another table environment. This is a very elegant solution.
I was solving the size issue before my placing it in a \begin{landscape}...\end{landscape} environment. However if I do the same thing now, the footer disappears. Do you happen to have any idea why that could be now? :/

Comment: Which footer do you refer to? The table notes? The page number?

Comment: The page number. The whole page is blank, even if I place \pagestyle{maincontentstyle} in all possible place around or in the table, threeparttable or landscape environment. I'm trying to figure out what in the table code this is due to.

Comment: @Mil this is not happening for me. Have you loaded `\usepackage{pdflscape}`?

Comment: Yes I have. This is weird. :/

Comment: well, if you take exactly my example and put a landscape around the `table`-environment, you will see the page number. Now you can add more and more of your packages until you see, what is doing the change. Get rid of this package, search for incompatibilities on this side or ask another question then.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another table with the same issue and will try to replicate the procedure in your answer. :)